# how to switch database name in mongoengine

Tags: database, pymongo, mongoengine

I have multiple databases with same collection names, document types, etc.

In source code at Github, documents use get_db method to choose the database to work on and in that method there is another call to get server connection. Both of these processes works with same parameter that called "alias".

Let's say that I have all my db connections defined with same server details and different databases, aliases. In that way, there will be multiple connections to same server. But it would be better if I could change database on a single connection. For example;

```
    import pymongo
    con = pymongo.connection(/* ... */)
    def dummyDBSwitch(db):
            global con
            return con[db]
```

Is it possible to switch database before querying?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We add some methods to mongoengine source and fix this need this way, details: https://github.com/cool-shark/mongoengine

Answer (score 0):

This isnt currently possible but will be looked at in 0.8.  Follow @metoikos's ticket: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/106

Comment: We have added that feature to Document/Connection pair but as you already know by the code, it doesn't work for querying part. That part is really complex to get involve without experience. Where should I start to begin to apply it? I tracked "Model".objects() method in source code and found where you add it but I have no clue where you parse/apply given parameters. I think that it would work if I could pass switch_db as a parameter in querying part. Any idea?