# switch db with mongoenine

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have an issue with switching my database in mongoengine. I want the following code works as expected:

```
class Test(Document):
    f1 = StringField()

db_names = ['s' + str(i) for i in range(5)]

for db_name in db_names:
    connect(db_name)
    for i in range(10):
        Test.objects.create(f1=uuid1().hex)
    disconnect(db_name)
```

I know about context_managers.switch_db and have looked to [how to switch database name in mongoengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173469/how-to-switch-database-name-in-mongoengine) but in my case it doesn't work. I need to switch my db for all models.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it?

> ```
> class Test(Document):
>     f1 = StringField()  
>
> db_names = [register_connection('s' + str(i), ... ) for i in range(5)]
> for db_name in db_names:
>     with switch_db(Test, db_name) as Test:
>     for i in range(10):
>         Test(f1=uuid1().hex).save()
> ```

For more about `register_connection` see `help(register_connection)` at console.

Comment: Yes, I solved this issue in that way. As for me it is not good sollution, because I have much models in different files. Did something like "for doc in me.base._document_registry.values(): if not issubclass(doc, moe.EmbeddedDocument): do_stuff()" . As for me it is not obvious.